# Is Chrome Driver necessary for Selenium

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am making a .Net Application and it uses Selenium to send messages from Whatsapp Web, I use the Chrome Driver with it and I want to know if I need to download the driver everywhere or if I can use it by implementing it into my application

Answer (score 0):

You don't need for this you can use web driver manager for any browser.[Webdriver manager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)